# Encoding of DBUnit Blob Column on JPA Entity

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, dbunit

I am creating some unit tests for some existing functionality.

I am using DBUnit with an embedded H2 database to test some JPA Entities.
Our production environment uses SQL Server.

The problem I am having is that I need to perform some operations on a Blob column on one of the entities but it seems that if I copy the contents of the Blob data from one of the SQL Server rows into my dbunit xml dataset, when I instantiate a String from the bytes it does not represent the text that I expect.

Snippet of the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mn_gateway_template")
public class GatewayTemplate implements Serializable {

@Lob
@Column(name = "config_file_bytes", length = 500000)
private byte[] configFileBytes;

}
```

To save the bytes I do this:

```
GatewayTemplate template = entityManager.find(GatewayTemplate.class, 1l);
byte[] bytes = postedStringContent.getBytes();
template.setConfigFileBytes(bytes);
entityManager.persist(template);
```

My dataset:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataset>
      <mn_gateway_template id="4" disabled="0" description="A config file" config_file_bytes="00101111  01101001  01101110  01110100" />
    </dataset>
```

My spring-test-mvc test:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
public void testSaveEditedTemplate() throws Exception {

    Account account = new Account();
    account.setId(1l);


    mvc.perform(
                post("/admin/gateway/config/template/save")
                        .sessionAttr("account", account)
                        .param("configTemplateFileName", "testConfig.txt")
                        .param("configFileText", "/log :info \"This is my config file \"")
                        .param("configurationOwnerAccount","1")
                        .param("model", "1")
                        .param("termsAccepted", "true")
                        .param("masterTemplateId", "1")

                    );

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    GatewayTemplate editedTemplate = entityManager.find(GatewayTemplate.class, 1l );
    Assert.assertEquals("/log :info \"This is my config file \"", editedTemplate.getConfigFileText());


}
```

The test is basically simulating the post of a String. I simply call the String.getBytes() method to get the Blob data and save it.
In the real application when I retrieve the Blob data and instantiate a String from it, the String represents exactly what I posted on the UI, but when the bytes are provided in the dataset with DBUnit the Assertion fails.See below.

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[/log :info "This is my config file "]> but was:<[Ѯ7�n9�^x㝴�5�n㝴�n�﮹�Μ��_�~�뾟�n�����������}�ѭ�ѭ��M��޸�N��޻�ޞ��獴��y���Nt�n=��5�n}�N�}���M��N��^�띴﮵�n��ε�m��m�ߝ��N��x�N������ѭ�~v�5�9�Nx�^6��9�M�뎶�������랜�Ο����޵������m���M��N�덴�n�뾽����Nt�n=��5�n}�N�}�N��x�N�]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at za.co.wifire.admin.api.controller.gateway.GatewayTemplateControllerTest.testSaveEditedTemplate(GatewayTemplateControllerTest.java:133)

I assume that this is due to encoding difference...

Comment: So why not present code, because right now there is nothing to comment on. Or a question

Comment: Have added code with a bit more info as requested.

Comment: How about the Entity? you know, the thing with this Blob. The persist of the Entity? The SQL invoked to persist the BLOB.

Comment: Added an example of persisting the entity with a relevant snippet of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that DBUnit only supports binary data in the form of a Base64 encoded string.

Think my problem is more in design than anything else. The blob column should actually be a simple string , but it was previously a blob to accommodate file uploads and cant be changed as it currently contains data that we need.